# html query string with blackberry

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

My hybrid mobile app needs to work on blackberry devices as well.

I noticed that a simple html query string such as

1. http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret

Works also this way using the anchor tag (even if it is not standard)

2. http://example.com/over/there#name=ferret

using Android and iOS.

I don't have a blackberry to try but I need to know if with bb the second method (with hash) will work or not.

**Question:**

Using a blackberry and javascript, will the below instruction 
change the page to example or not?

`location.href('http://example.com/over/there#name=ferret');`

Please I need an empirical response

Thanks

Comment: I've looked on the internets and my guess is that it doesnt matter, but isnt there a blackberry simulator that you can test it on?

Comment: I dont even have a bb SDK and never used it, where did u read it?

Comment: I think it might be smart to download one then, Titanium Studio supports Blackberry sdk's so that might be a smart choice. Titanium studio is a crossplatform develop enviorment

Comment: Check BB's official developer site, installing and running the emulator is actually pretty painless: https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it does work, I tried with a bb device (on the same network) using 2 html pages in my localhost.